# auto ownership but not a resident

Tags: united-states, traffic, texas

I intend to move overseas for a few years. I expect to return to the US periodically and will need a car when I do.

Can I purchase and license a car for my use in the US?

Can I use a post office box as an address for this?

Comment: In what state do you intend to keep the car?

Comment: Have you compared the price of owing to renting/leasing while you are in the US?

Comment: Probably Texas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may own a vehicle in Texas although you are not a US citizen nor residnt in the US. [This page](https://www.txdmv.gov/motorists/buying-or-selling-a-vehicle) From ther Texas Division of Motor Vehicles (DMV) gives some information, and has a link to the [Application for Texas Title and/or Registration (Form 130-U)](https://www.txdmv.gov/sites/default/files/form_files/130-U.pdf) and [its instructions](https://www.txdmv.gov/sites/default/files/form_files/VTR-130-UIF.pdf).

The form specifically lists a passport issued by a non-US country as an acceptable form of ID. The form requires a mailing address, but neither the form nor its instructions specify that the address must be a residence, nor that it must be in Texas or the US. You could apparently list an address outside the US or use a PO Box. You can also list an email address for reminders, such as renewals. Thre web page suggests tjhat further question can be asked via a telephone call to (888) 368-4689 or (512) 465-3000, or an email to askDMV@txdmv.gov. Other information is available from [this DMV site](https://www.txdmv.gov/)

If ther vehicle comes from outside Texas, the DMV page on ["Out of State and Imported Vehicles"](https://www.txdmv.gov/motorists/buying-or-selling-a-vehicle/out-of-state-and-foreign-vehicles) gives directions.

Registration requires current liability insurance, title does not, but it is not lawful to drive the vehicle without proper insurance. and registration